# Pushing vector<double> onto vector<vector<double>>

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

So, I have this situation:

```
vector<vector<double>> myVector; 
myVector.resize(somePreviousObject.size());
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    vector<double> tempVector;
    //Do some stuff that fills tempVector, in a loop
    //After loop:
    myVector[i].push_back(tempVector);
}
```

However, this produces a compile error, stating that:

```
no matching function for call to 'std:;vector<double, std::allocator<double > >::push_back(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)'
...stl_vector.h:733 note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = double, _Alloc = std::allocator<double>]
```

I realize that using a vector of vectors is not performance-friendly, but it still should compile and execute, correct?  Why doesn't it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the expression:

```
myVector[i].push_back(tempVector);
```

The subexpression `myVector` is a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, `myVector[i]` is a `std::vector<double>&`, and `push_back` on that vector requires a `double`, not a `std::vector<double>`.

It looks like you want to set the *i*-th element to be `tempVector`, if that is the case you should do (on the assumption that you don't need `tempVector` after this statement):

```
myVector[i].swap(tempVector);
```

(While `myVector[i] = tempVector;` will have the same net effect, it will be more expensive as it will allocate and copy all of the contents. The `swap` will *move* the contents of `tempVector` into `myVector[i]` at almost no cost (three pointer swaps))

I know someone will come along and suggest using `myVector[i] = std::move(tempVector)`, which is also fine in C++11, but not available in C++03. The difference between the two is that in the case of `swap` the original contents of `myVector[i]` are guaranteed to be inside `tempVector` after the operation (in this case `myVector[i]` was empty, so it won't matter). On the other hand, the state of `tempVector` after `myVector[i] = std::move(tempVector);` is undefined in the standard, it could leave the vector empty, or it could swap it or... the only guarantee is that the `tempVector` object can be destroyed after the move.

Comment: I think that exploiting `swap` for constant-time assignments of values (in which case you want to discard the source) could be hidden nicely in a little helper object which does the swap() in the destructor. Something like `container_update<std::vector<int>> tmp(myVector[i]);` which maintains a std::vector<int> internally and swaps it with myVector[i] as soon as the `tmp` object goes out of scope.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I understand what you say, but I don't share the opinion. Code should be clear on what it does. If the operation was more complex I would add a helper, but being what it is I see no point. Also note that `swap` has other side effects (`tmpVector` changes) which might not be obvious just looking at the function call. Finally, I would find it much easier to read by removing the code altogether and using a reference: `std::vector<double> & tempVector = myVector[i];` (but this means the container will be updated even if the old assignment line is not reached)

Comment: Ahhh man I feel really silly.  I'll stick with the C++03 swap method rather than the C++11 move, as I can't guarantee the userbase will have C++11.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Just using a reference was my first thought as well, but then you lose the commit semantics indeed (which may become an issue if you start having exceptions in the middle). As for the helper object - I totally agree, code should be clear on *what* it does. The raw `swap` line is *how* it does it, but *what* it does, the intention of the code, is to update the value of the vector `myVector[i]`. Another benefit of the helper object is that the source of the swap (the one which, in this case, gets emptied) can no longer be accessed after the swap.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: What it does is not really *update* the element, but *move* the temporary vector into the container. In C++11 that is `std::move`, in C++03 the idiomatic way is swap as in the *copy-and-swap* idiom. Does `container_update<...> tmp(...); tmp.push_back(x);` modify the original container or only when it goes out of scope? Will it copy or move the elements? Those are the details that your abstraction is hiding.

Answer (score 2):

It's either

```
myVector[i] = tempVector;
```

or

```
myVector.push_back(tempVector);
```

Since you resized your vector beforehand, I'm assuming you want the first version.

In your code, remember that `myVector[i]` is itself a `vector<double>`, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas never used that before. Is it better than `=`?

Comment: It won't allocate the space and copy all of the contents from `tempVector` to `myVector[i]`, but rather *move* the contents (i.e. no memory allocations, no copies, just three pointer swaps). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<vector<double>> myVector;
```

should be:

```
vector<vector<double> > myVector;
```

and then

```
myVector[i].push_back(tempVector);
```

should be

```
myVector.push_back(tempVector);
```

Comment: The first difference depends on the compiler. C++11 makes that syntax valid, so we can no longer bash VS for accepting invalid syntax.